# Using residuals from regression as new dependent variable in another regression

Tags: regression, residuals

My code is below. I first open and read in data from a file and compute a least squares regression model and a regression model using a Copula method to account for endogeneity of one of the independent variables.
Then I save the residuals from the Copula method.
I would like to use these residuals as a dependent variable in a third regression model using the same independent variables as the first two models.

It appears I need to add the residuals to the dataset data matrix or do I?

```
library(REndo)
dataset = read.csv("c:/users/rocke/onedrive/desktop/2019F1R.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))

# Estimate team regression first in OLS and Copula

model1 = lm(rankfinish ~ teamdnf + pollpos + log(teamexp) + devpittime, data = dataset)
summary(model1)
model2 = copulaCorrection(rankfinish ~ teamdnf + pollpos + log(teamexp) + devpittime | continuous(pollpos), data = dataset)
summary(model2)

# Save residuals from Copula regression

errors = resid(model2)
```

Comment: As you have multiple variables is a good idea to try vinereg package.  also, try `model2$residuals` if it is returned by the function.